# PowerShell shell script running window auto close: Start-Process vs ./

Tags: powershell, git-bash

Say that I have a shell script called `myscript.sh` in current dir.

Both `Start-Process myscript.sh` and `./myscript.sh` will run the script in a new bash window, but with 1 major difference in behaviors:

if I choose to `./myscript.sh` after the script ends the window closes automatically, and I get no chance to see the output, whereas `Start-Process` does not close the new window.

I wonder why, and if there is a way to change it, since `./` is ultimately shorter and esier to call than `Start-Process`.

Edit:
Below is the bash opened by PS after running script. I believe this is a git bash?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmZKY.png)

Edit:
Question solved, or actually it went by itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell cannot itself execute `.sh` scripts, so it relies on the system's GUI shell (the so-called [Windows shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell)) to tell it how to open such files.

Your system seems to be configured to open (execute) such files with *Git Bash*, the Bash version that comes with [a Git installation on Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/).

However, there should be *no* difference between invoking `./myscript.sh` or `Start-Process ./myscript.sh`: both should *asynchronously* run the script with Bash in a *new window*, namely a MINGW64 console window.

Note that the only way to run such scripts is in a separate window, because the Bash that comes with Git cannot run in regular console windows.
Generally, any file whose extension is not listed in `$env:PATHEXT` as directly executable will run in a new (possibly GUI) window.

A Bash shell invoked with the path of a script to execute *automatically exits* after the script to execute has terminated, which closes the window it runs in as well.

To prevent the window from closing automatically, you can follow the script execution with a command that waits for a keypress; e.g.:

```sh
& $env:ProgramFiles\Git\git-bash.exe -c './myscript.sh; read -n 1 -p \"Press a key to exit.\"'
```

This still results in *asynchronous* execution, however; to get *synchronous* execution - i.e., to wait until the Bash window has closed, you must combine the above with `Start-Process -Wait`:

```sh
Start-Process -Wait $env:ProgramFiles\Git\git-bash.exe -Args '-c "./myscript.sh; read -n 1 -p \"Press a key to exit.\""'
```

Comment: Thanks, @SeVe - there was indeed a problem, namely with respect to _quoting_: please see my update. The `-c`, however, is still needed: without it, you cannot execute _multiple commands_, as is needed here. Your attempt would try to execute non-existent script `./myscript.sh;` (i.e., the `;` would be considered part of the name) and pass all remaining arguments to that script.

Comment: Ah thanks for clarification @mklement0 . I only had to execute a single command and therefore it also worked for me without the '-c' :)

Comment: @SeVe, yeah: without `-c`, the first (non-option) argument must be  script file path, and all remaining arguments, if any, are passed through to that script.